# How to run react native expo?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run expo start but the following error occurs:

> Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
>       at ChildProcess.packagerProcess.once (/@expo/xdl@56.1.3/src/Project.js:1602:16)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)

Comment: Did you try this? `expo init project => cd project => expo start`

Comment: Yes, when I do this occurs this problem.

Comment: Could you try this? `export BABEL_CACHE_PATH=/tmp`  OR  You can try reinstall `npm -g install expo-cli` and `expo init`